# Cannot build ns3 after upgrading to MAC OX 10.9

Tags: g++, clang++, osx-mavericks, ns-3

It is really a bed news that NS3 cannot be built after upgrading to MAC OX 10.9. I try to solve this but nothing changed after 10 hours work. Followings are some errors:

"clang: error: argument unused during compilation: '-compatibility_version 1'"

"/src/wifi/model/ideal-wifi-manager.h:80:10: error: private field 'm_minSnr' is not used [-Werror,-Wunused-private-field]"

So if you have not upgrade your system, do not do that.

And if you guys know how to solve this, I really appreciate your answers.

After I search the Internet, it seems that OS X 10.9 does not support g++ and use clang instead. I really have no clue on how to solve this.

Thanks.

Comment: This problem is due to OS X 10.9 moving to Xcode 5.0.1, which no longer 
includes gcc compiler.  Instead, the Apple LLVM compiler is provided. 

The NS community will solve this problem soon. 

https://www.nsnam.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1784#c1

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact solution. 
I also spent a lot of time trying to install ns-3 on mavericks and eventually gave up. I realized that the location of the Xcode 5.0.1 command line tools necessary for installing ns-3 has changed and you still need to install a lot of other programs. (I got libgcc sth not found)

My suggestion, if you can't wait and really need ns-3 on your mac, is to partition your hard drive install a linux (I tried ubuntu), and install ns-3 on that instead. (I found it much faster) Make sure you read all the minimum requirements [here](http://www.nsnam.org/wiki/Installation) and install all the suggested software.